# Wordpress: Cart get empty when payment fails

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I tried this...
Goto WooCommerce > Settings > Products > Inventory and remove any value that is present in the Hold Stock (minutes) field.

Normally that is set to 60 minutes (to reserve inventory). If an order is not paid, then WC will cancel the order and release the inventory for use.

But this doesn't affect my problem.
Is there any other solution available for this problem.
For the note, I' using the Paytm payment gateway and Paypal's payment gateway.

Comment: I think it is a better idea to ask your question at wordpress.stackexchange.com instead of stackoverflow and remove this one.

Comment: I agree with Mr Ali, This is more of a Plugin related qeustion so the Actual Forum is better here's that link for you. 

https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/woocommerce/

Answer (score 0):

So the query was solved. As I'm using the paytm payment gateway and also PayPal payment gateway so when I approach to cancel the payment using the Paypal it restored my cart with an item but when I approach to cancel the payment using the paytm it doesn't restore the cart with items. So basically its plugin problem, as Paytm payment gateway plugin doesn't have that facility to restore the cart if we cancel the payment made using the paytm. So, if same problem occurs to you ask for help with the payment gateway developer as I ask paytm payment gateway developer.